# Faster plotting in matplotlib or better options

Tags: python, performance, matplotlib, plot, data-visualization

I am trying to visualize some data for a log of close to 25,000 data points. When running this with matplotlib.pyplot on Python it is taking a really long time to render simple line graphs, and sometimes I've had to simply exit out from it taking 10+ minutes. This data log was made for sampling purposes, and real data logs can be a lot higher compared to this (some files can be several gigabytes long).

With this in mind, is there any way to plot data this big in matplotlib, without extremely slow execution? Or is there perhaps another framework that can do this a lot better in python? I understand that it can still take a while to render at that size, but for practical purposes, taking 10+ minutes for each plot really is not useful. Any help or guides are appreciated.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('sample.txt', low_memory=False) #25k Lines of data
df = df.iloc[:-2, :] # dropping last two rows since we don't need them
#'some_column' and 'another_column_name' for example purposes
#Both are 25k lines long
y = some_column 
x = df[another_column_name] 
x.pop(0) #removing unnecessary value, ignore this

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

tmpy = df[y]
tmpy.pop(0) # removing unnecessary value, ignore this

ax.plot(x, tmpy) # plot x against y 
ax.set_title('Sample Graph')

plt.show()
```

In here I try to basically plot a column from the Pandas dataframe against another column. Very simple plotting to try and produce a line graph. The columns consist of some integers but mostly decimal values. It takes a really long time to do just this sample, real files are much bigger as mentioned. The goal is to be able to accomplish this with any file that is input.

Comment: matplotlib is very slow indeed, but it should clearly not take 10 minutes to draw plots with 25000 points. Anyway it is not gonna be able to print gigabytes of data in a reasonable time, but I hardly think the resulting plots could be readable... There are several other tools to make plots/data-representations with different feature/results compared to matplotlib. The actual question is: which kind of representation do you precisely need. Just basic line graphs?

Comment: Yes, for the purposes of what I'm graphing I just need line plots.

Comment: Are you plotting the lines one-by-one? Or in one go?  A very common problem is that when one uses strings instead of numbers, matplotlib will indicate each string at the axes, which is slow, unreadable and usually not what you want.

Comment: I plotted 25000 lines and 25000 points in a heatmap, and both plots took less than 20 s. Something in your code slows the plotting down but without posting it, what do you expect here as an answer?

Comment: If you do not care about fancy features like axis, legends, text rendering, you can use low-level graphical library like OpenGL which is very very fast (eg. millions of lines can be drawn per seconds) although it is cumbersome to use. **VTK** is a quite fast library to manage huge amount of data in a reasonable time (it use low-level libraries internally with a native code). That being said, I am able to plot a million a point in a bit less than a second on my machine with matplotlib using the critical case `plt.plot(np.arange(1000_000), np.random.rand(1000_000)-0.5); plt.savefig('test.png')`

Comment: @Mr.T I added some of my code now, if that helps.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Thank you, I will look into that. That's really fat plotting for a million points.

Comment: No, it is not matplotlib, and it is not your code. A random sample of 25000 points took only some seconds. matplotlib 3.5.1, pandas 1.3.5, QtAgg backend. Have you timed each step to find out which of them takes so long?

Comment: @Mr.T When it executes plt.show() is where it really just slows down immensely. Everything else runs quickly and I identified this in my own source code already.  I figured it had something to do with matplotlibs rendering, but at this point im not really sure, given that you and others have shown it execute quickly.

Comment: Can you provide a more reproducible code? For example by providing the input that is slow and the chosen columns. On my machine this is quite fast too (about 1 second with matplotlib 3.4.3 and TkAgg as the backend).

Comment: I figured it out! So apparently when Pandas was reading in the file it was storing the values as 'object' types not a 'float64', which is what numbers are. Adjusting this fixed the issue and I am now able to plot as quick as some of you mentioned. Thank you!

Comment: There are some valuable lessons here. 1) Always check dtypes (especially when it comes to datetimes). It might seem reasonable to assume a dtype but pandas might interpret the data differently. 2) Always test with a small sample. Then you would have noticed that each datapoint is labelled (slowing down the rendering because each individual label has to be printed) and that the labels are evenly spaced but not plotted in numerical order. 3) (Nearly) always listen to JohanC. He was on the right track from the beginning.